# Переопределение методов

Tags: java, ооп

При переопределении метода можно расширять модификатор доступа,но сузить нельзя. Почему? Этот вопрос прозвучал уже на этом сайте,и был один ответ,связанный с принципом подстановки Лисков.Я не так хорошо понял связь между этим принципом и сужением модификатора доступа.Не могли бы объяснить поподробней или пример какой то привести?

Comment: Суть принципа Лисков (на сколько я понимаю) в том, что если мы функции, принимающей параметром объект базового класса передадим объект потомка, то функция этого не заметит и правильно отработает. Если мы в потомке сузим модификатор доступа метода, к которому она обращается, то функция не сможет нормально отработать, поскольку не получит доступа к нужному методу (java не знаю, прошу сильно не бить за возможные неточности в терминологии)

Comment: Да, Юрий на мой взгляд корректно объяснил. Просто представьте себе ситуацию, в которой Ваш метод работает с классом Animal и использует его метод move. Если сделать метод move приватным в наследнике (например в классе Dog), то всё ломается...